# Google sheets output function data to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Is it even possible to display the result of the SUM function in another cell.
For example. in cell A1, the function =SUM(E3:E), but the result must be displayed in cell D1.

Is this even possible in theory or not?

Comment: No, only by script.

Comment: Mike Steelson tnx

Comment: Put in the cell A1 **=SUM(E3:E)**, then you can just copy the result to  another cell, like this D1 **=A1**

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be achieved but only when you use array notation.
To have in D3 sum of e3:e but the formula in A1:

You write in A1

```
={"","","",sum(e3:e)}
```

This produces 3 empty cells in A1,B1,C1 and displays sum in D1

(in countries that use comma as decimal separator you should write:

```
={""\""\""\sum(e3:e)}
```